# Customizing Django User by subclassing AbstractUser

Tags: django

In my app i have a model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
```

In settings.py i do the following:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'forum.User'
```

After performing synchronization, migrations and creating a superuser i still cannot log in. Cannot understand if i missed something in settings or anywhere else? Django docs say that this should be enough.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

by default.

Comment: Does superuser exist in database? How you create it?

Comment: Yes it is. I created it by manage.py command "createsuperuser".

Answer (score 0):

This is a plural setting / warning flags are going up all over the place in my brain about checking if it's iterable.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#authentication-backends

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
#                                                                     ^ add this
```

Comment: Still have an error while trying to authenticate though i did syncdb, migrations and created a superuser anew.

Comment: I've found out that all of my passwords are considered unusable because hash OF EVERY PASSWORD starts from UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX that is '!'. Does it mean that anyway i need to create custom backend for user creation?

Comment: As far as i can see now passwords stored in tables MADE BY SOUTH are invalid unlike passwords stored in tables MADE BY SYNCDB.